# Flex End Of File EOF encountered inside an action

Tags: flex-lexer

I am trying to start learning Flex this is my first try but I am getting this error
I looked for a little solution, but I couldn't find the right solution
Why? How can I solve this problem?
This my First Try

```
%%

([Ii][Nn][Tt])                  {printf("MotCle");}
([Ff][Ll][Oo][Aa][Tt])          {printf("MotCle");}
([Cc][Oo][Dd][Ee])              {printf("MotCle");}
([Cc][Ll][Aa][Ss][Ss][Ee])      {printf("MotCle");}
([Ss][Ii])                      {printf("MotCle");}
([Ss][Ii][Nn][Oo][Nn])          {printf("MotCle");}
([Ii][Ss])                      {printf("MotCle");}
([Tt][Qq])                      {printf("MotCle");}
([Qq][Tt])                      {printf("MotCle");}
([Rr][Pp][Tt])                  {printf("MotCle");}
([Jj][Ss][Qq])                  {printf("MotCle");}
([Ll][Rr][Ee])                  {printf("MotCle");}
([Vv][Rr][Aa][Ai])              {printf("MotCle");}
([Ff][Aa][Uu][Xx])              {printf("MotCle");}
([-+]?[0-9])+                   {printf("Entier");}
([a-zA-Z0-9])+                  {printf("Id");}
(\".+[ ]+\n?.+\")               {printf("ChaineDeChar");}
\/\/[^"\n"]*\n                  {printf("Commentaire");}
\/\* ([^"\n"]|*+[^/*])* \/\*    {printf("MultCommentaire ");}
([ ])+          {printf("Blanc ");}
\Backspace      {printf("Backspace ");}
\t              {printf("Tab");}
\n              {printf("EOL");}
\f              {printf("FormFeed ");}
","             {printf("VIR");}
"+"             {printf("PLUS");}
"-"             {printf("MOINS");}
"*"             {printf("MULT");}
"/"             {printf("DIV");}
"="             {printf("AFF");}
">"             {printf("Graet Then");}
">="            {printf("Graet Then or Equale");}
"<"             {printf("Less Then");}
"<="            {printf("Less Then or Equale");}
"=="            {printf("Equale");}
"!="            {printf("DIFF ");}
"&"             {printf("Et");}
"|"             {printf("OU");}
"!"             {printf("NON");}
"("             {printf("Parentese Ovrent");}
")"             {printf("Parentese Fermet");}

%%

int yywrap()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{

printf(" My First Try ");
yylex();
return 0;

}
```

This is a message that appears to me when I try to implement

```
line 64: EOF encountered inside an action
```

Comment: Which is line 64?

Answer (score 2):

The pattern here:

```
\/\* ([^"\n"]|*+[^/*])* \/\*    {printf("MultCommentaire ");}
```

is `\/\*` because patterns end at the first unescaped whitespace.

That's not the only erroneous pattern, nor is it even the only error in that pattern. But it's what is producing that error message. Look closely and you will see that the "action" -- which starts after the whitespace -- includes an unterminated comment.

Comment: @mr.Unusual: why should it? You didn't fix the problem. **Patterns cannot contain unescaped whitespace.**